# Backup of MongoDB collection data and rename the collections

Tags: backup, mongodb

I want to take a collections data backup on a different host, with renaming the Collections.

I am very new to **MongoDB**. Please help me with this task.

Comment: What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: **MongoDB Version 4**

Answer (score 0):

You can with this command rename your collection: 
    `db.rrecord.renameCollection("record")`

Then backup with this:
    `mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 3017 --username user --password "pass" --out /opt/backup/file`

Tip: You can specify different host for save your backup file.